# No module named zope.index

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, zope, python-dedupe

Getting the following error when trying to import a lib that depends on zope

No module named zope.index

my python path is correct (I can import other libs)
I already created an **init**.py file in the zope folder but it still isnt working so Im not sure what I might be missing

currently using python 3.7

*edit
Error:

File "C:\Users\vitor.valentim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\dedupe\tfidf.py", line 5, in 
    from .canopy_index import CanopyIndex

File "C:\Users\vitor.valentim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\dedupe\canopy_index.py", line 3, in 
    from zope.index.text.lexicon import Lexicon

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zope.index'

[zope path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8vsR.png)

[zope.index path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9w75n.png)

Comment: Please do not include images of code or errors. Paste their output (formatted) here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message `No module named zope.index` implies that import found a package `zope`, but then failed to find `zope.index` (otherwise the error message would be `No module named zope`).

Try

```
import zope
print(zope)
```

and see what that resolves to, something like this often happens if there is something shadowing the package you're trying to import.

Comment: Print returned: <module 'zope' from 'C:\\Users\\vitor.valentim\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\zope\\__init__.py'>  seems like python is looking on the wrong folder (looking at the anaconda folder when it should be looking at the python37 one). How can I fix this? Im using spyder